# Android panorama view

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view, 360-panorama-viewer, google-vr-sdk

So, I am building an application, something like google streets and I need to achieve next:

I need some kind of view(Google VR view or Panorama View) to achieve the same effect as google streets, to be able to rotate and see whole 360 picture, to be able to add visuals(like on google streets if there is a coffee house, I can see it has a marker and click on it) and to be able to move around(like on google streets, clicking on the road will move you to the next position). With what library, SDK or whatever is this possible to do?

Comment: did you find any solution to open street view into VR like street view app yet?

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Cardboard SDK.It Comes with a sample app Treasure Hunt may be you will get some idea from that.

https://developers.google.com/vr/cardboard/overview

https://developers.google.com/vr/android/get-started

Answer (score 0):

please use these libraries :-

https://code.google.com/archive/p/panoramagl-android/

https://developers.google.com/streetview/

https://developers.google.com/streetview/android